# Why and how did Marcus Messner join the army in Indignation?

Tags: plot-explanation, indignation

I watched the movie [**Indignation**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4193394/), a love story of Marcus Messner and Olivia Huttons. One thing about the story I can't understand is **why and how Marcus Messner joined the army while he was ambitious to become a barrister?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcus did not choose to join the army.  He was drafted, because he lost his exemption when he was expelled from school.